# Sublime Text 2 doesn't have the same indent as Notepad++

Tags: sublimetext2, notepad++, geany

I just moved from Geany to Sublime Text. It has a lot of pleasant features but I just can't get used to the indentation. I used Geany mainly because I could configure the indentation level exactly like it was on Notepad++ (Auto indent mode : Basic).

For example:

```
<element>
    <element>ENTER
    indent here
```

On Sublime text:

```
<element>
    <element>ENTER
        indent here
```

I would like to know how to have the same indentation as Geany (Mode Basic) and Notepad++.

In my config file on Sublime Text I added:

```
"auto_indent": true,
"smart_indent": false
```

which is not enough.

Comment: As far as I can see what you want is disabling the indentation, not "dumb" indent.

Comment: I want to disable the smart indent, not just indent. Disabling indent just return at the beginning of the line.

Answer (score 1):

The indent is controlled by the chosen syntax. I get the described behaviour when I choose the XML Syntax on Sublime Text 3 (3065, Mac).

Try another syntax like HTML, and you should get the indent you want.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, actually my syntax was already on html. But just switching to sublime text 3 instead of 2 got me the right behaviour.